# QTableWidget setItem in for loop only add data in last row

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying below code to add rows returned by sql query to QTableWidget but ending up having only last row has data and all other rows are blank. Though it inserts correct number of rows and columns

tried with print statements in each loop with row number column number and data. everything seems good

```
def show_all(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("toDoManager.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    all_rows = cur.execute("SELECT * from tasks").fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    self.tableWidget_taskResults.setRowCount(0)
    for row_num, row_data in enumerate(all_rows):
        self.tableWidget_taskResults.insertRow(row_num)
        #print(row_num,row_data)
        self.tableWidget_taskResults.setColumnCount(0)
        for col_num, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
            self.tableWidget_taskResults.insertColumn(col_num)
            #print(row_num,col_num,col_data)
            self.tableWidget_taskResults.setItem(row_num,col_num,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(col_data)))
            #print("widget data ", QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(col_data)))
```

Comment: Why are you setting the column count back to zero for every row? Set the row and column counts *before* the loop (`setRowCount(len(all_rows)); setColumnCount(len(all_rows[0]))`) - then there's no need to explicitly insert any rows and columns.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you. after adding above lines to set row columns and deleting insert row, column lines from loop. it worked perfect for me. It was method name that got me confusing.